# Where can I find a Prime class documentation

Tags: ruby, documentation

If i use Prime class like this:

```
Prime.new
```

I'll get next message:

```
Prime::new is obsolete. use Prime::instance or class methods of Prime.
```

I [tryied finding](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mathn/rdoc/index.html) this class documentation, but couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have it locally through `ri`:

```
$ ri Prime

= Prime < Object

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
= Includes:
Enumerable (from ruby core)

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The set of all prime numbers.

== Example
     Prime.each(100) do |prime|
       p prime  #=> 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ...., 97
     end

== Retrieving the instance
Prime.new is obsolete. Now Prime has the default instance and you can access
it as Prime.instance.
...
```

There's also RubyDoc.info which has a better index:

> http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/prime/1.9.2/frames

Comment: Hm... "Nothing known about Prime"

Comment: @demas: Does `ri` work for anything for you?

Comment: Yes, ri works for Fixnum class, for example

Comment: @demas: Does `ri --list-doc-dirs` look sensible?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems not to be published yet at ruby-doc.org. But you could have a look [at the commented source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/prime.rb) for now; it includes usage examples.